# mounting remote network drive using sshfs

Tags: sshfs

I am using win-sshfs to mount a remote drive from a Debian Linux server on a windows 7 64-bit desktop machine over the internet. The drive works but it is slow. I want to speed up win-sshfs by disabling compression and encryption. How can I do this? Otherwise is there a faster alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest installing samba on your debian server or maybe a ftp server for large file transfers.

FTP is unencrypted and you can set different compression options,
windows can map a ftp:// share in explorer without any tools

Comment: SSH (Secure Shell) is not SSL (Secure Sockets Layer). "Slow" can be the result of low bandwidth (compression might help here if the files are suitable for that) or a not-so-powerful CPU (weaker ciphers may help here).

Comment: Please don't recomend FTP to people anymore. This isn't 1999 any more.